# Check if a workflow has crashed before triggering

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

We have a reasonably stable system running on SP 2007 which involved 3/4 key workflows.

I've noticed that if a user starts a workflow but behind the scenes it crashed and they then try to run that worklow again they get a visible error, namely the "Exception from HRESULT: 0x8102009B" error.

If I then go in an manually stop the crashed/running workflow then things go back to runinng smoothly. So my questions are:

1. When running a workflow is there a way to check that this workflow has already been run and crashed previously?
2. If a worklfow crashes can the system send an email to our SP support team?

Many thanks,

S

Comment: Hi Stephen, have you checked the ULS logs to get more details on the error?

Comment: Hey spStacker yes we did get the logs and they all seem fine, it seems sometimes the workflow is running twice?!